# The number of $j$-dimensional subspaces which contain a given $i$-dimensional subspace.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $V=F_q^n$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over the $q$-element field $F_q$ ($q$ is a prime number). Given a $i$-dimensional subspace of $V$. What is the number of the $j$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ which contain the given $i$-dimensional subspace ($j>i$). In the case $n=4$, $i=1$, $j=3$, the number is ${3 \brack 1}_q = \frac{q^3-1}{q-1}$. What is this number in general? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint (*lattice correspondence*): if $W\le V$ then

$$\{A:W\le A\le V\}\cong\{B:0\le B\le V/W\}.$$

Make this correspondence more precise by partitioning each set according to dimension.

This reduces the problem to counting fixed dimension subspaces of a given finite vector space.